# Entity Framework 1:0..1 (One to zero or one) relationship using Data Annotations

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-6

Trying to do something that I believe should be simple.

```
Customer
------
CustId
BillingId 
ShippingId 
...other customerInfo

Address
------
Id
...other addressinfo
```

I have the corresponding POCOs

```
public class Customer {
    [Key]
    public int CustId {get;set;}

    [Column("BillingId")]
    [ForeignKey("BillingAddress")
    public int? BillingId {get;set;}
    public virtual Address BillingAddress{get;set;}

    [Column("ShippingId")]
    [ForeignKey("ShippingAddress")
    public int? ShippingId {get;set;}
    public virtual Address ShippingAddress{get;set;}

    ...others...
}

public class Address {
    [Key]
    public int AddressId{get;set}

    ... others...
}
```

The `BillingId` and `ShippingId` are `nullable` because the customer may or may not have set an address yet. I'd assume with EF that if the values are null, the `ShippingAddress` and `BillingAddress` values should also be `null`. When I take a look at the object I'm getting back when running the application, all of the data on my `Customer` object is set but on the `ShippingAddress`/`BillingAddress` fields, in debug mode when I inspect the object, I get the below error:

```
BillingAddress = '((System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.CustomerD_E865AA67CAAA399D4F193A2439775301DFD2F05115619BC048699B20BF6F7B11)details).BillingAddress' 
threw an exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException'
```

A same error appears for the `ShippingAddress` field. The application actually continues to run, the exception only gets thrown when inspecting in debug more. For the particular inspected object, the `ShippingId` and `BillingId` are populated correctly.

Not sure why this is happening given my setup.

Answer (score 0):

one possible reason is: your repository is registered as singleton in DI configure.

another possible reason: add `ForeignKey` and `InverseProperty` to navigation properties

```
public class Customer {
    [Key]
    public int CustId {get;set;}

    //[Column("BillingId")]//not necessary if real column is same as property
    public int? BillingId {get;set;}

    [ForeignKey("BillingId")]
    [InverseProperty("Customer")]
    public Address BillingAddress{get;set;} //no need to be virtual

    //[Column("ShippingId")]
    public int? ShippingId {get;set;}

    [ForeignKey("ShippingId")]
    [InverseProperty("Customer")]//InverseProperty: Specifies the inverse of a navigation property that represents the other end of the same relationship.
    public Address ShippingAddress{get;set;} //no need to be virtual

    ...others...
}
```

try `Scaffold-DbContext` in a new project to validate your pocos:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/cli/powershell#scaffold-dbcontext

```
Scaffold-DbContext "your connection string" -DataAnnotations -OutputDir "Models" -Force
```